# How do I configure ActiveJob to use Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, rails-activejob

I am having a bit of difficulty with ActiveJob in Rails 4.2 and Resque.

I've installed redis and I've added resque and resque-scheduler to my Gemfile.

I've created a test job - it is just the generated file

```
rails g job test
```

but I keep getting errors about ActiveJob not defined

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveJob
```

or missing method when I switch the adapter like this

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque
```

I get this error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_job' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f97ba98a5b8> (NoMethodError)
```

I've even looked at the source code but I have no idea. It is just calling super.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb#L95

What I am missing?  Why doesn't the queue adapter work?  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turns out that I had selected which frameworks I was using.

```
# config/application.rb 
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

The way to fix it, is to add the Active Job framework in the application.rb file.

```
require "active_job/railtie"
```

Or to load all of Rails

```
require 'rails/all'
```

This seems to be working now.

Comment: What file would I add `require "rails/all"` to? I tried adding it to my resque.rake file but I still get "uninitialized constant ActiveJob". I don't have rails 4.2 installed and am trying to use ActiveJob as a gem so maybe this is my problem.

Comment: config/application.rb is the file that needs to be modified.  I've updated the answer to include this.  Please consider up voting.

Comment: @Marklar I just realized that you are not yet on rails 4.2, so that is the problem.  If you are on 4.2 then follow the above instructions.  I have not used it as a gem so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 2):

Add them the Gemfile with gem 'resque' and gem 'resque-scheduler' and bundle install. We'll also need to create a Resque configuration file:

```
#config/initializers/resque.rb

Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => "localhost", :port => 6379)
```

We'll also require the Resque and Resque Scheduler rake tasks, so we can start our workers and scheduler with rake:
    #lib/tasks/resque.rake

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque-scheduler'
  end
end
```

We can now start a worker with `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work`. If everything's working right, we should be able to see it in the Resque console. Run `resque-web` and visit http://0.0.0.0:5678/overview.

All we really need to do is configure it to use the Resque adapter.

```
#config/initializers/active_job.rb

ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :resque
```

Now adding Jobs and enquing them should work as expected.
Also try updating rails gem if you see `undefined ActiveJob`.